# LinearLayout not wrapping Button views of different font size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a screen to input pin numbers. I've used a vertical linear layout. Within this linear layout I've created 4 horizontal linear layout. In these linear layouts I've buttons as fixed width and height. For same font size of the button text it is displaying well but when I decrease the font size of the last 2 buttons then those 2 buttons are clipped within the horizontal linear layout. Please see the screen shot for better explanation.

[With different button font sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98f1n.png)

[With same button font sizes (40sp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D3VQ.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   style="@style/RootLayout"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <include layout="@layout/actionbar_login"/>
   <TextView
      style="@style/TextViewLarge"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:text="@string/welcome"/>
   <TextView
      style="@style/TextViewNormal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:text="@string/enter_pin"/>
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
      <View
         android:layout_width="15dp"
         android:layout_height="15dp"
         android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_1"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_2"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_3"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_4"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_5"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_6"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_7"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_8"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_9"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="0"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="@string/_0"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
      <Button
         android:layout_width="70dp"
         android:layout_height="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_pin_button"
         android:text="0"
         android:textColor="@drawable/selector_pin_button_text"
         android:textSize="40sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: numbers are one digit and letters are 6 and more digits

Comment: Then it should keep the text within 70dp width and height why it is moving entire button to bottom?

Comment: The linearlayout is wrap content. If it is moving buttons to bottom at least it should not clip buttons.

Comment: @HiteshGupta try using the layout_weight attribute

Comment: After using layout_weight it is not clipping buttons but still pushing it downwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Button as view in Android has some base parameters (style) for text setting to "text" parameters, image to "background" and so on. 
Just try to use another view elements for you task. For ex. simple TextView.

Another problem, it's wrap_content of your parent ViewGroup, which can increase his size by different reasons.